# Scala: Invokation of methods with/without () with overridable implicits

Tags: scala, overriding, implicit

Here is a definition of method, that uses `ExecutionContext` implicitly, and allows client to override it. Two execution contexts are used to test it:

```
val defaultEc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))
```

Names of threads look like: 'pool-1-thread-1' to 'pool-1-thread-5'

And the 2nd one from Scala:

```
scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Names of threads look like: 'scala-execution-context-global-11'

Client can override default implicit via:

```
implicit val newEc = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Unfortunately it is overridable only, when a method with implicit is invoked without `()`:

```
val r = FutureClient.f("testDefault") //prints scala-execution-context-global-11
```

not working:

```
val r = FutureClient.f("testDefault")() //still prints: pool-1-thread-1
```

The question is WHY it works this way? Cause it makes it much more complicated for clients of API

Here is a full code to run it and play:

```
object FutureClient {
  //thread names will be from 'pool-1-thread-1' to 'pool-1-thread-5'
  val defaultEc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))

  def f(beans: String)
           (implicit executor:ExecutionContext = defaultEc)
  : Future[String] = Future {
    println("thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(Random.nextInt(3))
    s"$beans"
  }
}

class FutureTest {
  //prints thread: pool-1-thread-1
  @Test def testFDefault(): Unit ={
    val r = FutureClient.f("testDefault")
    while (!r.isCompleted) {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2)
    }
  }

  //thread: scala-execution-context-global-11
  @Test def testFOverridable(): Unit ={
    implicit val newEc = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    val r = FutureClient.f("testDefault")
    while (!r.isCompleted) {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2)
    }
  }

  //prints pool-1-thread-1, but not 'scala-execution-context-global-11'
  //cause the client invokes f with () at the end
  @Test def testFOverridableWrong(): Unit ={
    implicit val newEc = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    val r = FutureClient.f("testDefault")()
    while (!r.isCompleted) {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2)
    }
  }
}
```

I have already discussed a couple of related topics, but they are related to API definition, so it is a new issue, not covered by those topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Scala Patterns To Avoid: Implicit Arguments With Default Values](https://www.wlangiewicz.com/2017/09/24/scala-patterns-avoid-implicit-arguments-default-values/)

`f("testDefault")` (or `f("testDefault")(implicitly)`) means that implicit argument is taken from implicit context.

`f("testDefault")(newEc)` means that you specify implicit argument explicitly. If you write `f("testDefault")()` this means that you specify implicit argument explicitly but since the value isn't provided it should be taken from default value.

Comment: @Dmitro Mitin, thank you for your answer. I agree with it. Unfortunately I cannot accept arguments in the article you mentioned. But it is another story.

Comment: current link is https://www.wlangiewicz.com/2017/09/24/scala-patterns-to-avoid-implicit-arguments-with-default-values/